# Select a record from 1 to many relationship with conditions

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have a Users Table. It has UserId, UserName, Email. I have a Address Table It has AddressId,Address,Country,Userid And addressType. One User can have either home or office address(AddressTypes) or both(He has at least one address).

I need to select a user with his address. If user have a office address it should be the selected address. If office address is not available then return home address.
What is the way to do this in maximum performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
WITH cteBest as ( 
    SELECT users.userID, COALESCE(O.AddrID, H.AddrID) as AddrID
    FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN Addr as O on users.userID = O.UserID and O.AddrType = 'Office'
               LEFT OUTER JOIN Addr as H on users.userID = H.UserID and H.AddrType = 'Home'
) SELECT Users.UserName, Users.Email,  Addr.* 
FROM cteBest INNER JOIN Addr on Addr.addrID = cteBest.AddrID
             INNER JOIN Users on Users.UserID = cteBest.UserID
```

This assumes each user has at least one of home/office and does not have more than one home or more than one office

EDIT: Also, if you want performance, make sure your Address table has an index for UserID. And of course Addr should have one for AddrID and Users should have one for UserID.

Answer (score 0):

```
USERS      ADRESS
------     ---------
USER_ID    ADDRESS_ID
USERNAME   ADDRESS
EMAIL      COUNTRY
           USER_ID
           ADDRESS_TYPE
```

I think I would use an analytical function to do that. row_number() over() for example:

if address_type O is office and H is home, when ordered descending O comes first and ordr value would be 1 for it. If there is no office address home address is first and the value is 1. Filtering values with ordr=1 would give you only one address and you can join it with user table.

```
select *
  from user u,
   (select user_id,
                    row_number() over(partition by user_id order by address_type desc) as     ordr
      from address a) ad
 where u.user_id = ad.user_id
 and ad.ordr= 1
```